# Styling an element by ID works, by class does not

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working with twitter bootstrap tables and am trying to assign my own style (background color) to a table's  elements.

What works: assigning `id="foo"` to each <td> element, and then placing `#foo { ... }` in my stylesheet.

What doesn't work: assigning `class="foo"` to each <td> element, and then placing `.foo { ... }` in my stylesheet. I have also tried styling by placing `td { ... }` and `tr td { ... }` in my stylesheet. Neither worked.

Why could this be? I thought maybe there could be a class of the same name lying around, but unless bootstrap has a class called ".asdfasdfasdfasdf" I'm pretty sure that isn't the case.

Comment: What are these elements?

Comment: Yes, please show some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing any actual code it's hard to tell, but I guess you have a CSS rule with a higher *specificity* that overrides your class. To track something like that use "*inspect*" in your browser to see which rule is overwriting your CSS class.

CSS precedence does work and is ordered like this:

- Element, Pseudo Element: *0,0,0,1*
- Class, Pseudo class, Attribute: *0,0,1,0*
- Id: *0,1,0,0*
- Inline Style: *1,0,0,0*

For example: If you have a rule like `#body table tr td {}` it will always have a higher precedence than `tr td {}` even than `body table tr td {}` or `tr td.someClass {}`.

You can read more about the *specificity* on this page: [Understanding Style Precedence in CSS: Specificity, Inheritance, and the Cascade](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/).

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I'm pretty new to CSS so this is just what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to mark the css values in your class as important.

```
.foo { 
     border: 1px solid black !important; 
}
```